# Enumerations of Hamiltonian paths on grid graphs (square lattices)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Here is my code to brute-force number of all possible undirected Hamiltonian paths on grid graph of dimensions `m*n`. It works up to `m,n<=6`. I did not even try it for `7`, I guess it would take too long.

```
hpathcount[m_,n_]:=Module[{g=GridGraph[{m,n}]},
Flatten[FindPath[g,#[[1]],#[[2]],{m*n-1},All]&/@Subsets[Range[m n],{2}],1]//Length]

to = 6;
Table[a[i, j] = hpathcount[i, j], {i, to}, {j, i, to}];
Array[a, {to, to}] /. a[m_, n_] -> a[n, m] // Grid
Clear[a, to]
```

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 4 & 8 & 14 & 22 & 32 \\
 1 & 8 & 20 & 62 & 132 & 336 \\
 1 & 14 & 62 & 276 & 1006 & 3610 \\
 1 & 22 & 132 & 1006 & 4324 & 26996 \\
 1 & 32 & 336 & 3610 & 26996 & 229348 \\
\end{array}$

Then I found the article [Transfer matrix method for enumeration and generation of compact self-avoiding walks. I. Square lattices](https://booksc.me/book/32922166/b11c7a) by Kloczkowski, A., Jernigan, R. L.

**Do you have any experience with their method?**

They are using some transfer matrix to do the enumeration. They give an example for `m=4` and arbitrary `n` to count Hamiltonian cycles (I am more interested in counting all Hamiltonian paths than only cycles, but there is only explicit example for cycles).

```
t = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}};
ut = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
v = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
Table[ut . MatrixPower[t, i] . v, {i, 1, 18}]
Clear[t, ut, v]

(*{2,6,14,37,92,236,596,1517,3846,9770,24794,62953,159800,405688,1029864,2614457,6637066,16849006}*)
```

The output means there are `2` cycles for `m=4, n=3`, `6` cycles for `m=4, n=4`, `14` cycles for `m=4, n=5` and so on. I am not quite sure why the formula does not work for `m=4, n=2`, which should give output `1`, but I got an error "matrix is singular".

**I do not understand how they constructed the transfer matrix `t` and other two matrices `ut` and `v`. They are explaining but I am not very familiar with graph theory so I hope someone with education in graph theory can help.**